# N-level tree or expandable list android

Tags: listview, tree, expandablelistview, android

I have a list of categories and subcategories and items under each category individually and also items under the subcategories. I would want to display this in a sliding layer , such that it only occupies a certain portion of the screen, with the main screen still visible.

I have looked at the expandable list view and also [tree-node structure](https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/source/browse) and also gone through [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17703/best-way-of-representing-hierarchical-data-in-android)

I even tried implementing my own expandable listview that extended to n-levels , was successful too but then the situations changed now. I was using POJO classes that had the relationships defined inside them that is subcategories iterating through the category POJO. But i am now using a cursor. It is possible to use cursors with expandable listviews, but never tried with n-level expandable list view. It would un-necessarily increase the number of queries to be made.

Could i have some clue as to where to begin from? The tree-node example is good but then it has the parent levels and all defined before head, while in my case, it may vary . multiple panels will not suit the requirement since multiple clicks and also space has to be considered.

**What i have i tried so far?**
I have coded an expandable listview, but i am having issues scrolling the listview, although i am not using it with any scrollview. Also, MeasureSpec is specified, but i dont know why it doesnt scroll.

Together with that i need to have items collection also with could be inside a category directly or inside subcategories. And for these items i am inflating a list view that is the row layout.

I modified the treee structure to set the levels in code, but the disadvantage and confusion lies in how the ids are used and how i should relate the child nodes with the group nodes.

Thanks for any help.